# Remove odd or even lines from a text file

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I need to remove odd lines in a text file to make a down-sampling. I've found this command,

```
awk 'NR%2==0' file
```

but it only prints the odd lines in the terminal. How to really remove them?

I don't really care for even or odd, I want them removed from the file or printed in another file. This only prints them in the terminal.

Comment: Are you sure that `awk 'NR%2==0' file` __prints__ odd lines?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

#### awk

The `%` is a modulus operator and `NR` is the current line number, so `NR%2==0` is true only for even lines and will invoke the default rule for them (`{ print $0 }`). Thus to *save only the even lines*, redirect the output from `awk` to a new file:

```
awk 'NR%2==0' infile > outfile
```

#### sed

You can accomplish the same thing with `sed`. [*devnulls*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21309169/1331399) answer shows how to do it with `GNU sed`.
Below are alternatives for versions of `sed` that do not have the `~` operator:

*keep odd lines*

```
sed 'n; d' infile > outfile
```

*keep even lines*

```
sed '1d; n; d' infile > outfile
```

Comment: Ok,I don't really care for even or odd, I want them removed from the file or printed in another file. This only prints them in the terminal.

Comment: Great stuff; just to complete the picture: `awk 'NR%2!=0' infile > outfile` saves the *odd* lines; with `awk`, you canNOT replace the input file *in place*, with `sed`, you can: use option `-i ''` (on Linux, just `-i` works, too).

Answer (score 18):

Using GNU sed:

```
sed -i '0~2d' filename
```

to remove the even numbered lines from the file.

For removing odd numbered lines:

```
sed -i '1~2d' filename
```

The `-i` option would cause the changes to be saved to the file in-place.

Quoting from the manual:

```
`FIRST~STEP'
     This GNU extension matches every STEPth line starting with line
     FIRST.  In particular, lines will be selected when there exists a
     non-negative N such that the current line-number equals FIRST + (N
     * STEP).  Thus, to select the odd-numbered lines, one would use
     `1~2'; to pick every third line starting with the second, `2~3'
     would be used; to pick every fifth line starting with the tenth,
     use `10~5'; and `50~0' is just an obscure way of saying `50'.
```

Comment: Great; to potentially save others a trip to `man sed`: address `m~n` means: "start with line m and match ever n-th line after" (and `d` means "delete").

Answer (score 13):

This might work for you (both GNU and non-GNU sed):

```
 sed -n 'p;n' file # keep odd
 sed -n 'n;p' file # keep even
```

`-n`: suppress printing

`p`: print current line

`n`: next line

Comment: `-n` means suppress printing. `p` means print this line. `n` means next line.

Comment: This answer is great because it works on non-gnu sed (e.g. mac) that doesn't support `~` operator.

Answer (score 5):

Don't focus on the negative (removing lines), focus on the positive (selecting lines) and your solution will follow suit. So instead of `I need to remove odd lines` you should be thinking `I need to select even lines` and then the solution is simply:

```
awk '!(NR%2)' file
```

If you want to save the result to a new file:

```
awk '!(NR%2)' file > newfile
```

or back to the original:

```
awk '!(NR%2)' file > newfile && mv newfile file
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an `awk` example to create two new files containing the odd and even lines, respectively:

```
awk '{ if (NR%2) print > "odd.txt"; else print > "even.txt" }' input.txt
```

Comment: ITYM to use `>`, not `>>` (remember this is awk, not shell). Also, you can abbreviate the whole thing to `{ print > ((NR%2?"odd":"even") ".txt") }`

Comment: Valid point, although if neither of the files existed beforehand, they're fairly equivalent. And the abbreviated code, at least to me, is a little less readable, so, while I might do it for scripts I maintain, I don't always recommend that level of terseness for others...

Answer (score 1):

Perl solution for printing evens to new file:

```
perl -lne 'print if $. % 2 == 0' infile > outfile
```

To print odds, change `== 1` to `== 0`

`$.` is the line number

Keeps only evens in the original file:

```
perl -i -lne 'print if $. % 2 == 0' infile
```

Same as above, but makes a backup file called infile.bak:

```
perl -i.bak -lne 'print if $. % 2 == 0' infile
```