# How to skip first line and delete odd lines

Tags: csv, awk, sed

I need to modify a csv file by skipping the first line and removing odd lines.

csv file:

```
name,tags,time,mean
server_1,a,2015-10-24T11:45:27.869918Z,620023.5521262008
name,tags,time,mean
server_2,b,2015-10-24T11:45:27.869918Z,0
name,tags,time,mean
server_3,c,2015-10-24T11:45:27.869918Z,0
name,tags,time,mean
server_4,d,2015-10-24T11:45:27.869918Z,66.16323731138544
```

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21309020/remove-odd-or-even-lines-from-text-file-in-terminal-in-linux) explains how to remove odd lines. But I don't know how to skip the first line and print it out like below:

```
name,tags,time,mean
server_1,a,2015-10-24T11:45:27.869918Z,620023.5521262008
server_2,b,2015-10-24T11:45:27.869918Z,0
server_3,c,2015-10-24T11:45:27.869918Z,0
server_4,d,2015-10-24T11:45:27.869918Z,66.16323731138544
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `awk`

```
awk 'NR==1 || !(NR%2)' file
```

or `gnu-sed`

```
sed -n '1p; 2~2p' file
```

or

```
sed '3~2d' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
awk 'NR%2==0 || NR==1' infile > outfile
```