# calculate mean on even and odd lines independently in bash

Tags: bash

I have a file with 2 columns and many rows. I would like to calculate the mean for each column for odd and even lines independantly, so that in the end I would have a file with 4 values: 2 columns with odd and even mean.
My file looks like this:

`2   4
4   4
6   8
3   5
6   9
2   1`

In the end I would like to obtain a file with the mean of 2,6,6 and 4,3,2 in the first column and the mean of 4,8,9 and 4,5,1 in the second column, that is:

`4.66   7
 3    3.33`

If anyone could give me some advice I'd really appreaciate it, for the moment I'm only able to calculate the mean for all rows (not even and odd). Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Try filtering even/odd lines first. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21309020/remove-odd-or-even-lines-from-a-text-file

Comment: I've edited the post!

Comment: bash cannot do floating point arithmetic.

Comment: Does the input file consist of integers only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an `awk` *hardcoded* example but you can get the point :

```
awk 'NR%2{e1+=$1;e2+=$2;c++;next}
     {o1+=$1;o2+=$2;d++}
     END{print e1/c"\t"e2/c"\n"o1/d"\t"o2/d}' your_file
4.66667 7
3       3.33333
```

Answer (score 1):

A more generalized version of Juan Diego Godoy's answer. Relies on GNU awk

```
gawk '
    {
        parity = NR % 2 == 1 ? "odd" : "even"
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
            sum[parity][i] += $i
            count[parity][i] += 1
        }
    }
    function result(parity) {
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
            printf "%g\t", sum[parity][i] / count[parity][i]
        print ""
    }
    END { result("odd"); result("even") }
'
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer uses Bash and `bc`. It assumes that the input file consists of only integers and that there is an even number of lines.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r oddcol1 oddcol2; read -r evencol1 evencol2
do
    (( oddcol1sum += oddcol1 ))
    (( oddcol2sum += oddcol2 ))
    (( evencol1sum += evencol1 ))
    (( evencol2sum += evencol2 ))
    (( count++ ))
done < inputfile

cat <<EOF | bc -l
    scale=2
    print "Odd Column 1 Mean: "; $oddcol1sum / $count
    print "Odd Column 2 Mean: "; $oddcol2sum / $count
    print "Even Column 1 Mean: "; $evencol1sum / $count
    print "Even Column 2 Mean: "; $evencol2sum / $count
EOF
```

It could be modified to use arrays to make it more flexible.